# Angular 2 does not redirect after login

Tags: angular, redirect, typescript, angular-routing

I am trying to redirect user after successful login. Here is the code:

```
login(event) {

event.preventDefault();

this.error = '';
this.loading = true;

this.authenticationService.login(this.user.email, this.user.password)
    .subscribe(result => {

      if (!result) {
        this.loginError();
        return;
      }

      this.loginSuccess();

    },
    err => {
      this.loginError();
    });

}
```

The authenticationService.login() method makes a HTTP POST. The loginSuccess() method is this one:

```
private loginSuccess() {
      this.router.navigate(['/app/dashboard']);
}
```

It seems this problem is something related with asynchronous methods once if I try to log in again it redirects. But, as far as I can tell, the router.navigate is only called after the request returns.

I noticed router.navigate() returns a ZoneAwarePromisse object. If it successfully redirects the object looks like:

```
__zone_symbol__state:true
__zone_symbol__value:true
```

However the failed one looks like:

```
__zone_symbol__state:true
__zone_symbol__value:false
```

Comment: (1) Have you tried looking at the server responses in the network traffic tab of your browser's dev-environment?  (2) Have you inserted console.log() statements to verify a) that the success function is called each time, b) that the result object is properly configured in all instances and c) that the error function is not being executed?   I am very interested in helping you resolve this, please let me know about the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your page sometimes redirects and sometimes does not is of great interest to me. Because it redirects sometimes, we can assume, for now, that the code you have displayed is correct and that the problem lay in the `authenticationService`.

Use console logging to carefully inspect the results and the order in which they appear.  Add lines like: `console.log('initializing login request')`, `console.log('success function called with result object', result)`, `console.log('inside success function with \'this\' object, this)`,`console.log('error function called with error', error)`.

This helps to review the values of the variables as they are appearing, and more importantly, you can also see when no function is executed at all... investigate these instances more thoroughly!

Make sure that while you do this you are reviewing the Network tab of your browser's development console.  Look at the message you are sending to ensure it is properly formatted. Look at the response. Did a response come back?  Was it formatted well?  Could there be a parsing error?  These are usually the points where my code fails.

In my code, the failure is often either a failed server response (no response at all) or a badly formatted one.  Sometimes the server adds error text to my JSON, and the JSON becomes non-parsable.  This gives me reason to find the error in the server-side code and that fixes everything.  Or it gives me reason to check the web server settings to ensure that my server has not failed or that the packets are being received and processed correctly.

I will update this answer as I learn more about your situation.  Good luck!

Comment: authenticationService also makes a HTTP request and that was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! That is what this community is here for :)